# Валидация массива

Tags: yii2

В моделе есть переменная `$array`, которая всегда является массивом. Так вот, нужно указать правило чтобы хотя бы один элемент массива был указан.
Пробовал так:
`[['array[0]'], 'required', 'message' => 'Обязательное'],`
На валидации получаю ошибку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно указать такое правило?

Comment: вам нужно создать [встроенный](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-) или [автономный](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-) валидатор

Comment: есть ещё [EachValidator](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-core-validators.md#yiivalidatorseachvalidatoreach-)

Comment: @Blacknife, пробовал такие варианты, не работает.
[['array'], function ($attribute, $params) {
    if(empty($this->array)){ //if(!$this->array[0])
         $this->addError('array', 'Обязательное!');
    }
}],
 
или
 
[['array'], 'hasNotEmptyArray'],
 
public function hasNotEmptyArray($attribute, $params)
{
   if (empty($this->array)) {
      $this->addError('array', 'Обязательное!');
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

К проверяемому свойству модели внутри валидатора нужно обращаться $this->attribute, а не $this->array

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['array'], function ($attribute, $params) {
            if (!count($this->attribute)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, "Массив не может быть пустым");
            }
        }],
    ];
}
```

Просто внимательней читайте доки